# How do I set image position in conky

Tags: conky

I copied and modified an existing .conkyrc file from the ubuntu forum and I'm trying to place the LinuxMint logo in a specific position Below are my conkyrc file and the screenshot

```
# UBUNTU-CONKY
# A comprehensive conky script, configured for use on
# Ubuntu / Debian Gnome, without the need for any external scripts.
#
# Based on conky-jc and the default .conkyrc.
# INCLUDES:
# - tail of /var/log/messages
# - netstat shows number of connections from your computer and application/PID making it. Kill spyware!
#
# -- Pengo
# 

# Create own window instead of using desktop (required in nautilus)
own_window yes
own_window_type desktop
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager

# Use double buffering (reduces flicker, may not work for everyone)
double_buffer yes

# fiddle with window
use_spacer right

# Use Xft?
use_xft yes
xftfont URW Gothic:size=8
xftalpha 0.8
text_buffer_size 2048

# Update interval in seconds
update_interval 3.0

# Minimum size of text area
# minimum_size 250 5

# Draw shades?
draw_shades no

# Text stuff
draw_outline no # amplifies text if yes
draw_borders no
uppercase no # set to yes if you want all text to be in uppercase

# Stippled borders?
stippled_borders 3

# border margins
border_margin 9

# border width
border_width 10

# Default colors and also border colors, grey90 == #e5e5e5
default_color grey

own_window_colour brown
own_window_transparent yes

# Text alignment, other possible values are commented
#alignment top_left
#alignment top_right
#alignment bottom_left
#alignment bottom_right.
alignment top_middle

# Gap between borders of screen and text
gap_x 10
gap_y 10

#Display temp in fahrenheit
temperature_unit fahrenheit

#Choose which screen on which to display

# stuff after 'TEXT' will be formatted on screen

TEXT
$color
${color green}SYSTEM ${hr 2}$color
$nodename $sysname $kernel on $machine
LinuxMint 11 "Katya" (Oneric)
${image ~/Conky/Logo_Linux_Mint.png -s 80x60 -f 86400}


${color green}CPU ${hr 2}$color
${freq}MHz   Load: ${loadavg}   Temp: ${hwmon temp 1}
$cpubar
${cpugraph 000000 ffffff}
NAME             PID       CPU%      MEM%
${top name 1} ${top pid 1}   ${top cpu 1}    ${top mem 1}
${top name 2} ${top pid 2}   ${top cpu 2}    ${top mem 2}
${top name 3} ${top pid 3}   ${top cpu 3}    ${top mem 3}
${top name 4} ${top pid 4}   ${top cpu 4}    ${top mem 4}

${color green}MEMORY / DISK ${hr 2}$color
RAM:   $memperc%   ${membar 6}$color
Swap:  $swapperc%   ${swapbar 6}$color

Root:  ${fs_free_perc /}%   ${fs_bar 6 /}$color 
hda1:  ${fs_free_perc /media/sda1}%   ${fs_bar 6 /media/sda1}$color

${color green}NETWORK (${addr eth1}) ${hr 2}$color
Down: $color${downspeed eth1} k/s ${alignr}Up: ${upspeed eth1} k/s
${downspeedgraph eth1 25,140 000000 ff0000} ${alignr}${upspeedgraph eth1 
25,140 000000 00ff00}$color
Total: ${totaldown eth1} ${alignr}Total: ${totalup eth1}
${execi 30 netstat -ept | grep ESTAB | awk '{print $9}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr}
${color green}LOGGING ${hr 2}$color
${execi 30 tail -n3 /var/log/messages | awk '{print " ",$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10}' | fold -w50}

${color green}FORTUNE ${hr 2}$color
${execi 120 fortune -s | fold -w50}
```

[image]

I want to put the mint logo right after the word (oneric).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer [here](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html).  I just needed to add -p (for position) and coordinates to the line that called the image.

```
${image ~/Conky/Logo_Linux_Mint.png -s 80x60 -f 86400}
```

became

```
${image ~/Conky/Logo_Linux_Mint.png -p 170,40 -s 80x60 -f 86400}
```